# SML NJ - match nonexhausitive - not sure how to handle

Tags: smlnj

I want to define a function that takes 3 parameters and returns a list.  The parameters will be of any type and then other two parameters are of lists of any types.  This is an example...

```
fun func x [y] [z] = [x, y, z];
```

Even though the function evaluates to the proper data types, I get a match non-exhaustive warning.

In this example, I don't get the same warning...

```
fun func x y = (y, x);
```

It should be because of the lists but I'm not sure how to handle it so I don't actually see a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that warning because you have only told your function what to do when passed an element and two lists, where each of the lists has only 1-element. What happens if one or both of those lists have fewer than 1 or more than 1 element?

Are you familiar with `@`? It might help you write the function that you seem intent on writing, but without that warning.

Comment: I was thinking that it would be doable with just one line but sounds like I need a few checks then for nils?  As for @, I am using it but for my main function

Comment: Yay I got it!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh I have two lines actually.  Not sure how to do it with one hmm.  my first line is "x nil nil = [x]" - now, I'm not so sure

Comment: @cpd1 Hint1: `@` knows how to handle `nil` with no need for special cases. Hint2: you don't *need* to use patterns when defining a function on lists -- identifiers can refer to lists directly. Usually the pattern matching style is the cleanest, but there are exceptions.

Comment: Thank you!   I didn't realize that was the case with @.  Now it doesn't give the warning and data types are exactly as I need them.  I'm not so sure what you mean by hint #2 though.  You've helped enough so up to you if you want to clarify.  Appreciate it :)

Comment: I assume that by now you have a function which merges the two lists and sticks the element at the front. For fun, see if you can modify the definition so that it sticks the element *between* the two lists. This is actually more motivated since, e.g. `f -1 [3,7,4] [2,5,6] = [3,7,4,-1,2,5,6]` can be thought of as a way of appending two lists in such a way that there is a delimiter between the elements of the two original lists. This sort of thing could be directly useful in e.g. char lists.